# Scrollviews stopped working after update to watchOS 6, did something change?

Tags: swift, watchos, ios13, watchos-6

I have an application that uses iOS, todayExtension and watchOS as targets.

Until the launch of the new iOS 13, everything was working fine, that week I downloaded the iOS 13 beta on my iPhone and the watchOS 6 on my watch. Then, suddenly my app loads its objects but when I try to show them on a WKInterfaceTable, it's freezed. The table is there, the number of elements are there, but I can't roll it with drag/crown, I can select a row, but I can't navigate through it.

I already tried moving it out from a group, now the TableView is only below the Interface Controller, so no object should be above the TableView.

[image: tableView outside container]

Btw, 
"Supports Running Without iOS App Installation" checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of remaking the bugged screens from mark zero, I found the answer: watchOS 6 is marking the "Fixed to the screen edges" as true by default, and this field made my screens no to scroll anymore!

[image]

I hope that no developer spend more hours on this nonsense like I did.